# How can I check if the user has some role from the list? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want the team to be used, only for a few roles.

How can I achieve this?

**CODE:**

```
 if(message.member.roles.cache.has('823259335010287657', '752935996718449367')) {
if (command === "test") {
  member.roles.add(role);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array#some()`, This will return true if the member has aleast 1 role from the array. I will place your role id's in an array to achieve this.

```
const roles = ['823259335010287657', '752935996718449367'];
const memberHasRole = roles.some(role => {
   message.member.roles.cache.has(role);
});

if (memberHasRole) {
   if (command === "test") {
      member.roles.add(role);
   }
}
```

[MDN Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)